# There is no directive with "exportAs" set to "bs-modal"

Tags: ng2-bootstrap

I would like to integrate child modal into my project following example at

```
https://valor-software.com/ng2-bootstrap/#/modals#static
```

but I got an exception showing as below:

There is no directive with "exportAs" set to "bs-modal". I searched on google and found an answer at this link but it didn't work.

```
https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-bootstrap/issues/667#issuecomment-235204534
```

This line doesn't work when I followed his solution:

import {MODAL_DIRECTIVES, BS_VIEW_PROVIDERS,ModalDirective} from 'ng2-bootstrap/ng2-bootstrap';

Anybody can help? Thanks.
My project is using:

```
 "ng2-bootstrap": "^1.2.4"
 "@angular/common": "2.4.3",
 "@angular/compiler": "2.4.3",
 "@angular/core": "2.4.3",
 "@angular/forms": "2.4.3",
 "@angular/http": "2.4.3",
```

Comment: it would be good if someone valor software did a tutorial on how to do this properly as these modals are a complete ball ache when you try to implement them in a real world scenario....

Comment: Yes, I agree with you. thanks

Answer (score 3):

I also used same modal from same link. So I got exactly the same error. The solution was for me like that: 
You should add `import {ModalModule} from 'ng2-bootstrap/modal'` line to your
app.module.ts and then import it like below. Just make sure using **forRoot()**.
Without it you'll keep getting error.

```
 @NgModule({
      imports: [
        ModalModule.forRoot()
      ]
```

After that you need to do this import operation for **yourpage.module.ts** , too. 
That solution worked for me, I hope for you ,too.

Note: by the way here is my versions:

- "ng2-bootstrap": "^1.3.3",
- "@angular/common": "2.4.8",
- "@angular/compiler": "2.4.8",
- "@angular/core": "2.4.8",
- "@angular/forms": "2.4.8",
- "@angular/http": "2.4.8",

Answer (score 1):

This Kind of a problem may be caused by either of the following two scenarios:
 1. You could be missing this line in your component
 `@ViewChild('childModal') public childModal: ModalDirective;`
 2. You could have omitted an import in your module declaration

```
    import {ModalModule} from "ng2-bootstrap";

        @NgModule({
      imports: [
            ModalModule.forRoot()
   ],
   declarations: [],
   providers: []
   })
   export class MyModule{}
```